# For all practical purposes can light be bent (without the help of gravity) or just reflected?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

For example, if a single beam of light was directed directly at the tangent of a semi circular mirror, would it be considered bending or redirecting many times to form a near circular pattern? When I say bend I mean in a curved trajectory, not at an angle.

Comment: What you refer to as a 'beam of light' is actually composed of many photons in a coherent superposition; you need to be more precise for a physically meaningful answer, or wait and hope someone is nice enough to nuance your question for you then answer it.

Comment: Certainly one can "bend" light by shining it through a medium that has an gradient in its index of refraction.

Comment: @HotLicks This is arguably not actually bending the light, but absorbing the photons and re-releasing new ones with a different velocity vector.  What gravity does is much more subtle.

Comment: @AlecRhea, the question seems to be about ray optics.

Comment: Diffraction might be thought of as bending light. For example, in a Gaussian laser beam, rays follow hyperbolic paths. But it can also be treated as a superposition of straight rays that interfere.

Comment: @ThePhoton How so?  The OP seems to be asking about the nature of bending light non-gravitationally; if we are only capable of answering the question in some very approximate limit like ray optics then so be it, but I don't think a very roughly approximated answer is being requested.

Comment: @AlecRhea, He asks about  a "beam of light", and the level of the question doesn't imply prior knowledge beyond high school physics. If you want to post an answer that jumps straight to quantum mechanics, I won't downvote. But I don't think that's what will teach OP the most.

Comment: @ThePhoton I secretly hope that a good answer to this question might serve as a nice 'laymans intro' to the problem of merging QM and GR based views of the universe, but I would need to spend more time thinking about how to show the formalisms colliding in an easy to understand way.

Comment: @Alec Rhea When I say a "beam of light that is what I'm referring to, a "stream" of photons that to the naked eye appears to be all in one piece.

Comment: @ThePhoton You are correct in your assumption that I am not out of high school yet. This question just arises from a discussion between me and a friend, trying to decide if you can actually bend light specifically with a curved mirror.

Comment: In optical fibers it even goes into loops.

Answer (score 5):

The phenomenon you're describing, of light being bent, is observed when light passes through a medium with progressively increasing, or decreasing refractive indexes.

You actually observe it when you see a mirage. When it's very hot, the temperature being progressively higher as you approach the ground, the refractive index decreases (because density decreases) and light coming from the sky is bent upwards explaining why you see "water" on the ground when it's very hot. When in fact, what you actually see is light from the sky being bent upwards into your eyes.

Hope my answer helped! :)

This image sums it up pretty well

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the well-explained answer, but I'm talking specifically about "curving" light with a semi-circular mirror.

Comment: Are you talking about light "sliding" on a curved mirror? If that's the case it's seems to me as it's theoretically possible, but not experimentally...

Answer (score 0):

a beam of light can be bent through an angle by sending it through a wedge-shaped piece of glass, requiring neither gravity nor reflection. this phenomenon is called refraction and can be studied in detail on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

> if a single beam of light was directed directly at the tangent of a semi circular mirror, would it be considered bending or redirecting many times to form a near circular pattern?

The problem with this plan is that it's not possible to make an infinitely narrow beam of light. Because of diffraction, the diameter of a beam of light is limited to roughly the wavelength of the light. And if you try to make a beam with a diameter close to this limit, it will diverge very quickly. To make a *collimated* beam (one that doesn't diverge very much), you have to make the diameter of the beam substantially larger.

So there's no way for all the light to travel exactly tangent to the mirror surface, and the end result will not be the light beam skimming along the surface to exit the other side of the hemisphere. Exactly what will happen depends on the exact shape of the mirror and the *beam profile*. You normally wouldn't try to understand this problem analytically but just use a computer simulation to approximate the result.

To answer the question in your title,

> can light be bent?

If you want to bend light, then it's more easily done with a prism or lens, or possibly gradient index optics, as described in another answer.

Comment: One thought after I wrote this: It's conceivable to get something like what OP suggested if the "semicircular mirror" is a dielectric mirror and the incoming beam approaches at the critical angle for total internal reflection (not tangent to the mirror surface).

Comment: Ok, then since it is impossible to have a beam that small, could you HYPOTHETICALLY do it? As for a prism or a lens, isn't that just refraction, which is for all intents and purposes is the reverse of reflection? If so, then it's still at an angle, so not a curve per say.

Comment: 1. Hypothetically under what circumstances? My comment above suggests one where it might be possible. 2.  Refraction isn't the opposite of reflection any more than a bicycle is the opposite of a car. 3. As shown in Gornemant's answer, refraction by a continuously varying-index medium can produce curved beams rather than sharp angles.